# RecordRTC Error: MediaRecorder API seems unable to record mimeType: audio/wav

Tags: javascript, angular, html, audio-recording, recordrtc

`MediaRecorder API seems unable to record mimeType: audio/wav` getting this error although I'm giving the type as audio/wav below is the code i'm trying to implement, actually I'm trying to record my voice and upload it to server for which i need to send in wave PCM format but in the browser console it show me this below image warning.

```
startRecording() {
  const mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true
  };
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
    .then(this.successCallback.bind(this));
}

successCallback(stream: MediaStream) {
  const options = {
    mimeType: 'audio/wav'
      };
      this.stream = stream;
      this.recordRTC = RecordRTC(stream, options);
      this.recordRTC.startRecording();
}

stopRecording() {
  const recordRTC = this.recordRTC;
  recordRTC.stopRecording(this.processVideo.bind(this));
  const stream = this.stream;
  stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
  stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
}

processVideo(audioVideoWebMURL) {
  const recordRTC = this.recordRTC;
  const recordedBlob = recordRTC.getBlob();     
}
```

here is the console report, although i'm able to record but the mimetype of the file is always audio/webm

[image]

And also tried passing recordtype as `StereoAudioRecorder`,but it says in angular `Cannot find name 'StereoAudioRecorder'`, here is screenshot of it.

[image]

Please any help on this would be highly appreciated, did try searching a lot but unfortunately dint find any solution for this.

Comment: On angular, you can use this: `var StereoAudioRecorder = require('recordrtc').StereoAudioRecorder` i.e. require-object returns all nested recorders including StereoAudioRecorder. E.g. `var RecordRTC = require('recordrtc`);` Now `var StereoAudioRecorder = RecordRTC.StereoAudioRecorder`.

Comment: @MuazKhan thank you very much it worked like a gem, just wanna check if you have idea of recordRTC in wav PCM format how to set the channels to 1 ?

Comment: @MuazKhan got it no worries, thanks for the response

Comment: @MuazKhan this is the solution. Feel free to post this as an answer so i can upvote